Open AI integration
I have basic OPEN AI account and I am developing a POC where the goal is to get data from JIRA and then analyze it using OPEN AI. There is no restriction on what to analyze and how much to analyze, I can make it as minimum as possible, I just want this to work once.
The following is my script for javascript to get data from user
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const form = document.getElementById("jqlForm");

  form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const project = document.getElementById("project").value.trim();
    const sprint  = document.getElementById("sprint").value.trim();
    const story   = document.getElementById("story").value.trim();

    let jql = `project = ${project} AND sprint = ${sprint}`;
    if (story) {
      jql += ` AND issuekey ~ "${story}"`;
    }

    const jqlInput = document.createElement("input");
    jqlInput.type  = "hidden";
    jqlInput.name  = "jql";
    jqlInput.value = jql;
    form.appendChild(jqlInput);

    form.submit();
  });
});

and for my web app I am using flask and hence the app.py is like
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import openai
from jira import JIRA

app = Flask(__name__)

JIRA_ACCESS_TOKEN = "myToken"
JIRA_URL          = "https://JIRAURL.atlassian.net/"
OPENAI_TOKEN      = "openAIToken"

openai.api_key    = OPENAI_TOKEN

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

def generate_summary(prompt, model="gpt-3.5-turbo"):
    try:
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model=model,
            messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
            max_tokens=150,  # Adjust based on your needs
            temperature=0.5,  # Adjust for creativity
            top_p=0.9  # Adjust for diversity
        )
        return response.choices[0].message["content"].strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return "Error: Unable to process request."

def get_sprint_context(sprint_summary, sprint):
    prompt = f"You are going to read a list of summary of defect tickets. I want you to analyze the list of defects encountered during {sprint} and provide a summary focusing on which area of the application has more problems, using project management language. Do not use bullet points and in short summary highlight the facts about problematic areas of my application."
    return generate_summary(f"List of defects: {sprint_summary}\n\n{prompt}")

def call_gpt(jira_ticket):
    prompt = f"This is the response from JIRA getIssue platform API. I want you to give a detailed analysis of this JIRA ticket: {jira_ticket}"
    return generate_summary(prompt)

@app.route("/sprint", methods=['POST'])
def sprint_context():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        jql = request.form.get("jql")  # Receive the JQL string from the frontend
        sprint = request.form.get("sprint")

        if jql and sprint:
            jira_client = JIRA(JIRA_URL, basic_auth=("authEmail@gmail.com", JIRA_ACCESS_TOKEN))
            issues = jira_client.search_issues(jql)
            summary = [issue.fields.summary for issue in issues]

            sprint_context = get_sprint_context(summary, sprint)

            return render_template('summary.html', my_string=sprint_context)
        else:
            return "Missing JQL or Sprint data", 400
    return "Invalid Request", 400

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

The problem I am facing is that when I create new API key on OPEN AI web and add and run this for first time, it directly says that I have crossed the limit range and this does not work hence, however, I need to solve this and make this work. It's burden POC, and I can make any changes whatever works, with least data, least analysis but same integration. Please suggest what can be done??

Can youu give the exact error message

This question is similar to: OpenAI API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This error comes many times. This is not an issue on your end.
I also faced the same issue. I had credits but the api key still said "OpenAI API error 429: "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing detail"
In order to avoid this problem you can test the following solution by inserting your key in the curl:
curl --location 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR-API-KEY}' \
--header 'Cookie: _cf_bm=JK13hz8bDzqGHlF4QHt0oeZZNQkxJmNfR2b6YHtLdDQ-1727799752-1.0.1.1-mbQSEsSobRx6J_PTAo2qi7TKzTp6T6lLr50eb7nFa9XoKeTrYp.mNVFUllRck.lnxxZoIrLX85NXSSyGXpkWrw; cfuvid=mY9O7cSq2gAT.MUJP4cx.eRL.vKnYmcHS74oGHFgUh0-1727798356054-0.0.1.1-604800000' \
--data '{
    "model": "gpt-4",
    "messages": [
      { "role": "system", "content": "You are a creative and vivid storyteller." },
      { "role": "user", "content": "Create an engaging and informative video script that explains the impact of Artificial Intelligence (AI) on healthcare" }
    ],
    "max_tokens": 300
  }'

before using in any project then try to regenerate if not works then contact Open AI. You can change the model according to the specifications.
